# Passing variable number of arguments to R function

Tags: r, functional-programming, ellipsis

I have a function that can receive variable (and unknown) number of arguments.
The simplest example would be

```
test <- function(...){
       print(length(list(...)))
}
```

This function is called from a Shiny app where user provides input arguments separated by comma.
Let's assume that I parse the arguments and I have them in a vector

```
args <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

How can I pass these arguments to the function `test` without explicitly calling

```
test(args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4])
```

In my case the above solution is not good, since the number of arguments is unknown and I cannot hard code it.

I cannot also modify the function `test` to receive all the arguments as a list (the function is part of a package which I can't/don't want to modify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `do.call`. `args` is a vector, `do.call` needs a list of arguments, we can convert `args` to list using `as.list`.

```
do.call(test, as.list(args))
#[1] 4
```